# How to complain about being bullied by moderator?

Tags: support, moderators

Is there any channel for us to complain when we are bullied by a moderator? I really hope that Stack Overflow can be a place which is fully transparant. If we were being bullied by a  moderator, the evidence should not be wiped off (edited or deleted) by the big bully (moderator). Also, I hope there is a tool for us to vote on the moderator that likes bullying so that everyone knows about his real face.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact --> Other --> Fill in the details, link to proof of what you claim and the team will handle this.

Comment: For what it's worth, everything but everything is logged. There's no way short of hacking the Stack Overflow database directly to "destroy" any evidence.

Comment: And for the record, I observed the evidence presented by this moderator, and support their actions. Please do not attempt to defraud the voting system in the future. Also, before you accuse them of censorship, I was the one who also deleted your off topic comments complaining about them on another question here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are talking about regular users with moderating privileges, you can flag for diamond mod (users with a ♦ next to their usernames) attention.

If you are talking about diamond moderators however, you can contact the team directly. Just click on the ["Contact Us"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link that you can find at the bottom of any page on the site.

As for "voting" on any user, moderator or not, because they engaged in inappropriate behaviour; that is not possible. Let those who can handle the situation. Don't start voting on users for any reason other than the quality of their contributions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will file a report via contact us form to them. Just hope that this forum is the place that is fair.

Comment: The team will certainly take each individual case seriously. Good luck.